# Symmetrization of a Function

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

Suppose we have a function $f(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ where $n$ is determined from outside (i.e. our function defined via a double blank `f(x__):=...`) I'm looking for a way to define a new function
$$
g(x_1, \cdots, x_n)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} f(x_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, x_{\sigma(n)})
$$
here $S_n$ is the permutation group and this operation is called symmetrization in mathematics. Obviously $F$ is also need to be defined via a double blank `g(x__)`.  I have a code for this

```
g[x__] := Total[f @@@ Permutations[List[x]]]
```

This code works fine except for one big downside. The functional form you get from $g$ looks good but you run into trouble when you want to calculate $g(x,x,y)$ for example. This is because `Permutations[{x,x,y}]` returns `(*out: {{x, x, y}, {x, y, x}, {y, x, x}}*)`. This is problematic since although as an argument of the function these two $x$'s are the same, they should be treated still differently! So the permutation set should in fact be
`(*out: {{x, x, y}, {x, y, x}, {x, x, y}, {x, y, x}, {y, x, x}, {y, x, x}}*)`

Ho can I resolve this issue? Or does anybody has a better Idea for calculating the symmetrization?

Comment: "they should be treated still differently" <- Could you explain why?  Is it because you require that extra factor of 2 in this case for normalization purposes?  The result will still be symmetric, as it should be.

Comment: Yes, exactly because of normalization. Also at the time I posted this question I had a bug in my code which made me believe permutations is not doing what I want it to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more general solution:

```
Clear[symm, pm]

symm[group_][f_][args___] := 
 With[{s = Function @@ {pm /@ GroupElements[group]}}, 
  Plus @@ f @@@ s[args]
 ]

pm[p_] :=
  With[{pl = PermutationList[p]}, 
  Append[Slot /@ pl, SlotSequence[1 + Length[pl]]]
  ]
```

Then `symm[group][f]` represents the symmetrized version of `f` based on some permutation group.

```
symm[SymmetricGroup[3]][f][x, y, z]
(* f[x, y, z] + f[x, z, y] + f[y, x, z] + f[y, z, x] + f[z, x, y] + f[z, y, x] *)
```

---

Another way to solve the problem you encountered is not to use `Permutations`, but use [`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html) instead:

```
Permute[{x, x, z}, #] & /@ GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[3]]

(* {{x, x, z}, {x, z, x}, {x, x, z}, {z, x, x}, {x, z, x}, {z, x, x}} *)
```

This won't care if there are repeated elements. It's not necessary to use `GroupElements`, you could just as well use `Permutations@Range[3]`.  I simply tried to keep it general.

Comment: This great thank you... Since your code is so general can I ask for a slight generalization? Suppose instead of $\sum_{g\in G} f(x_{g(1)}\cdots x_{g(n)})$ ($G$ being the group is question) I was looking for the more general form $\sum_{g\in G} \chi(g) f(x_{g(1)}\cdots x_{g(n)})$ where $\chi$ is a function of group elements. Is there a way to modify your code to include this one too? e.g. the group is symmetric group and $\chi(g)=\mathrm{signature}(g)$.

Comment: @Hamed Good question, actually I also thought about it and I don't know how to do it *well* off-hand ... I'm not very familiar with the group theory functionality, either in Mathematica, or with the mathematics in general (though I'd love to learn it someday).  The symbolic tensors functionality does something very similar, except it's for the permutation of tensor indices, not for function variables. See things [like this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125410/12).

Answer (score 8):

You could make a list from 1 to `n`, where `n` is the length of the input, and create a permutation with that list. Then, replace each number with the corresponding input.

e.g.

```
g[x__] := Total[
  f @@@ (Permutations[Range[Length[List[x]]]] /. a_Integer :> List[x][[a]])
 ]
```

---

```
In[181]:= g[x, x, y]

Out[181]= 2 f[x, x, y] + 2 f[x, y, x] + 2 f[y, x, x]
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I also had a 0^0 issue somewhere too. This works perfectly.